# Javascript - Put icon/image on page while loading page content and use it on some JS event

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working with domready event of javascript. Using this event I am displaying processing icon after user submitting a form to show user that form is processing.

Problem is that, processing icon is adding properly but as it gets added first time on page, it take some time to load on page. So it not displaying to user and processing of form is goes on.

I need to load this processing icon while loading a form or page. So, after submitting form, it will appear and display on page.

Please note, in my case I should have to add icon by adding image tag like

```
<img src='images/loading.gif' style='border:0 none; height:20px;width:20px;' alt='Subitting...'>
```

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload your icon by running this JavaScript code when the page is first loaded:

```
var imgLoading = new Image;
imgLoading.src = 'images/loading.gif';
```

You don't need to wait for domready or anything like that before running that code; you can do it during the initial page load or any time after.